# Java implementing the delete methid in a skip list

Tags: java, skip-lists

The delete method for my skip list is going in an infinite loop! I followed the pseudo code from this website http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Map/skip-list-impl.html . The other methods seems to be working fine except the delete. This is my code:

```
public void delete(String k) {
    SkipListEntry p = findEntry(k);

    if (p.key != k) {
        return; // Not found, don't remove
    }

    while (p != null) {
        //need to delete the entry from each list using the "up" or "down" links
        p.left.right = p.right;
        p.right.left = p.left;  
    }
}
```

This is my entire code http://pastebin.com/StJRzixN

Thanks

Comment: You never update `p` in your loop. How do you expect `p != null` to ever change value?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a step in `delete`.

Before the recursive call, you need to assign `p` the value of `p.up`.

Otherwise, you sit on the lowest tiered `p` and just keep adjusting the neighbors' `right` and `left` pointers.